# How to drop a pandas column based on number of values in it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, dataset

Turns out that when trying to drop a column with categorical data (0s and 1s) I cannot get the desired result. I have tried several procedures but they all yield the same result: the dataframe itself with all columns.

```
df1.drop([i for i in df1 if df1[i].nunique == 2], axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

That's one way I tried. Another one is as follows:

```
df1.drop(df.columns[df.apply(lambda col: col.nunique == 2)], axis = 1)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is perfect. You just need to add `()` to `df1[i].nunique` so that it becomes like this: `df1.drop([i for i in df1 if df1[i].nunique() == 2], axis = 1, inplace = True)`

Answer (score 1):

one approach could be to get all the columns which are boolean  and drop then as below, this will work if the data type in column is correctly classified. choose to pass the datatype .dtypes as appropriate

```
bool_col = []
for cols in df:
    if df[col].dtypes == "bool":
        non_floats.append(col)
df = df.drop(columns=non_floats)
```